# Mongo Cluster Primary Unresponsive in Replica Mode

Tags: mongodb, performance

We have a Production Mongo Cluster in 3 node replication mode. All three nodes are run as docker containers and the image version used is 4.0.3.
This has been running fine for past 6 months. However, we started noticing slowness on the primary followed by completely unresponsive primary leading to unresponsive cluster. If we remove the secondaries out of the cluster, then the primary is able to service requests normally.

We noticed high number of open connections at the time of slowness/unresponsiveness, hence set maxIdleTimeMS to 3000 for the frequently used services. Also, added indexes for the queries with high read operations. This helped for a week’s time. But again it is back to the same state.
We cleaned up the data out of the secondaries, before adding them back to the cluster. It stays fine for a day’s time and then will start to slowdown and within few hours will become unresponsive.

The io statistics shows high %util

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          15.85    0.00    0.94    0.67    0.00   82.53

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme0n1           0.00     0.29  266.95  559.41  4755.07  5241.06    24.19     1.68    2.04    0.62    2.72   0.27  22.68

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          11.64    0.00    1.01    5.22    0.00   82.14

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00 3285.00   59.00 65684.00   854.75    39.80     2.37    0.71    0.71    0.84   0.29  96.45

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          10.33    0.00    1.02    5.57    0.00   83.08

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00 3750.50   46.50 87238.00   825.75    46.39     2.76    0.73    0.73    0.80   0.26  98.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           7.61    0.00    0.77    9.25    0.00   82.37

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00 1265.50 3598.00 25356.00 37972.50    26.04    27.85    5.71    3.72    6.41   0.20  99.65

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           6.62    0.00    0.49   11.26    0.00   81.64

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme0n1           0.00     6.00  574.50 3002.00 11870.00 42819.50    30.58    34.48    9.65    9.97    9.59   0.28 100.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           6.17    0.00    0.58    9.35    0.00   83.90

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00  520.00 3067.50 11376.00 37288.00    27.13    31.56    8.80    8.87    8.79   0.28  99.95

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           7.01    0.00    0.64    9.71    0.00   82.63

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00  489.00 2877.50 11076.00 38558.00    29.49    31.46    9.35    9.20    9.37   0.30 100.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           7.75    0.00    0.65   10.22    0.00   81.39

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00  465.00 2949.00  8782.00 46693.75    32.50    31.39    9.21    9.13    9.22   0.29  99.90

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           6.63    0.00    0.69    9.91    0.00   82.77

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00  522.50 2873.50 11540.00 38163.75    29.27    31.40    9.25    9.27    9.24   0.29 100.00
```

We also noticed that the percentage of the WiredTiger cache that is in use was around 80 to 85% at the time of issue.

```
insert query update delete getmore command dirty  used flushes vsize   res qrw  arw net_in net_out conn set repl                time
    47   743    631     71     108    41|0  0.4% 80.0%       0 49.9G 35.4G 0|0 13|0   748k    105m  469 rs0  PRI Jul  6 13:22:31.149
   125   706    462     58     100    39|0  0.5% 80.0%       0 49.9G 35.4G 0|0 14|1   627k   91.9m  459 rs0  PRI Jul  6 13:22:32.153
    99   682    487     60      94    60|0  0.6% 80.3%       0 49.9G 35.4G 0|0 15|0   685k   84.9m  458 rs0  PRI Jul  6 13:22:33.148
    43   684    418     43      85    52|0  0.6% 80.7%       0 49.9G 35.4G 0|0 15|0   539k   74.4m  457 rs0  PRI Jul  6 13:22:34.149
    40   602    391     47      64    52|0  0.7% 80.3%       0 49.9G 35.4G 0|1 18|0   573k   74.5m  457 rs0  PRI Jul  6 13:22:35.152
```

Please suggest possible solutions, debugging options.

Comment: what's the read preference you are using in application connections? Is there any latency between primary and secondary nodes?

Comment: Read preference is default(primary). There is no replication latency/lag until primary becomes unresponsive. After primary becomes unresponsive, the lag starts to grow.

Comment: Then use read preference **secondary** which reduces the load from the primary. and also check logs for slow queries.

Comment: Choosing read preference as secondary may return stale data right? And in a scenario where secondary is not available, how will this get handled?

Comment: The major question that we have is why primary becomes slow/unresponsive if the secondaries are added and is working fine all alone where all read/writes are directed to that single node.

Comment: have you checked mongod logs?

Comment: by default write concern use majority so write will commit only once **majority** of nodes have written data successfully. See this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/

Comment: The mongod logs shows higher active connections at the time of unresponsiveness.  If changing read preference and write concern help with the issue. Can you suggest best possible settings for the same?

Comment: you can test with readpreference  to nearest with slatesecond option first if you don't want any stale data.

Comment: Sure @ROHITKHURANA. We will try this out. Thanks.